# Numpy minimum in (row, column) format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

How can I know the (row, column) index of the minimum of a numpy array/matrix?

For example, if `A = array([[1, 2], [3, 0]])`, I want to get `(1, 1)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use [`unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
numpy.unravel_index(A.argmin(), A.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks, but to comment this is surely a incredibly complex syntax for doing a simple stuff.

Comment: it really is quite standard syntax, simple even...its just one function extra function call beyond A.argmin(), which returns an index....

Comment: @linello, just create a function and reuse it, the complexity of the syntax doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

[Corrected typo]

Another simple solution is

```
ri, ci = A.argmin()//A.shape[1], A.argmin()%A.shape[1]
```

As numpy.argmin returns the index reading in row-major order

---

Yes, you are right, it was a typo, which worked for square matrix