# Numpy: get the column and row index of the minimum value of a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example,

```
x = array([[1,2,3],[3,2,5],[9,0,2]])
some_func(x) gives (2,1)
```

I know one can do it by a custom function:

```
def find_min_idx(x):
    k = x.argmin()
    ncol = x.shape[1]
    return k/ncol, k%ncol
```

However, I am wondering if there's a numpy built-in function that does this faster.

Thanks.

EDIT: thanks for the answers. I tested their speeds as follows:

```
%timeit np.unravel_index(x.argmin(), x.shape)
#100000 loops, best of 3: 4.67 µs per loop

%timeit np.where(x==x.min())
#100000 loops, best of 3: 12.7 µs per loop

%timeit find_min_idx(x) # this is using the custom function above
#100000 loops, best of 3: 2.44 µs per loop
```

Seems the custom function is actually faster than unravel_index() and where(). unravel_index() does similar things as the custom function plus the overhead of checking extra arguments. where() is capable of returning multiple indices but is significantly slower for my purpose. Perhaps pure python code is not that slow for doing just two simple arithmetic and the custom function approach is as fast as one can get.

Comment: `np.where(x == np.min(x))`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may use `np.where`:

```
In [9]: np.where(x == np.min(x))
Out[9]: (array([2]), array([1]))
```

Also as @senderle mentioned in comment, to get values in an array, you can use `np.argwhere`:

```
In [21]: np.argwhere(x == np.min(x))
Out[21]: array([[2, 1]])
```

#### Updated:

As OP's times show, and much clearer that `argmin` is desired (no duplicated mins etc.), one way I think may slightly improve OP's original approach is to use `divmod`:

```
divmod(x.argmin(), x.shape[1])
```

Timed them and you will find that extra bits of speed, not much but still an improvement.

```
%timeit find_min_idx(x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 µs per loop

%timeit divmod(x.argmin(), x.shape[1])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop
```

If you are really concerned about performance, you may take a look at **cython**.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `argwhere` as well -- depends on whether NH needs the values to be usable as indices or as values in an array.

Comment: Though looking at it more that distinction only holds when the minimum value occurs more than once.

Comment: @senderle, OP has a working solution so I am not surprised that can be easily converted like `tuple(map(int, np.where(x == np.min(x))))`

Answer (score 24):

You can use [np.unravel_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)

```
print(np.unravel_index(x.argmin(), x.shape))
(2, 1)
```

Comment: very nice, does OP wants the minimum value of array or single item among arrays?

Comment: If this is the answer, isn't this whole question a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230067/numpy-minimum-in-row-column-format)?

Comment: @Anzel, I am not sure was just going by what the OP was using.

Comment: Revisiting my last comment -- this works for indexing or as a sequence of indices, but only because `argmin` returns just one value, even if the minimum occurs multiple times. The `where(x == np.min(x))` solution can capture multiple minima.

Comment: @senderle, true, I just presumed this was what the OP wanted as their own method will do the same.

Comment: Quite right. I'm just obsessively working through all the details, probably to an unnecessary degree!

Comment: @DSM, you might be right but I don't know if I am right yet.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you for the answer, a single item should suffice. It's indeed a built-in function solution but it doesn't seem to be faster at least for my simple example.

Comment: @Anzel thank you for the answer. where() is what I tried first, but it's considerably slower, probably due to scanning all elements for an extra of two times (testing equality and finding the index of Trues).

Comment: @N.H. I have an update which mainly slightly improved of what you've done already as the times show it's the fastest in your liking. Interestingly you leave comment to me on someone's answer :-) I'm sure Padraic is nice enough not to mind our ignorance.