# Get Row and Column with Minimum value in Entire Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

The problem is simple and so must be solution but I am not able to find it.

I want to find which row and column in Pandas DataFrame has minimum value and how much is it.

I have tried following code (in addition to various combinations):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[4,5,6],[2,1,3],[7,0,5],[2,5,3]], 
                 index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'], 
                 columns=['C1','C2','C3'])

print(df)

print(df.loc[df.idxmin(axis=0), df.idxmin(axis=1)])
```

The dataframe (df) being searched is:

```
    C1  C2  C3
R1   4   5   6
R2   2   1   3
R3   7   0   5
R4   2   5   3
```

Output for the `loc` command:

```
    C1  C2  C2  C1
R2   2   1   1   2
R3   7   0   0   7
R2   2   1   1   2
```

What I need is:

```
    C2
R3   0
```

How can I get this simple result?

Comment: Performance is important?

Comment: Working with some missing values is most important. Then display and then performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
a, b = df.stack().idxmin()
print(df.loc[[a], [b]])
    C2
R3   0
```

Another @John Zwinck solution working with missing values - use [`numpy.nanargmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanargmin.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[4,5,6],[2,np.nan,3],[7,0,5],[2,5,3]], 
    index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'], 
    columns=['C1','C2','C3'])

print(df)
    C1   C2  C3
R1   4  5.0   6
R2   2  NaN   3
R3   7  0.0   5
R4   2  5.0   3

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230123
ri, ci = np.unravel_index(np.nanargmin(df.values), df.shape)
print(df.iloc[[ri], [ci]])
     C2
R3  0.0
```

Comment: Great. Forgot to add in question: there are some np.nan values in real df. Will this code work there as well?

Comment: @rnso - sure, pandas function working with nans nice.

Comment: @rnso - changed solution for working with missing values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get the index this way:

```
np.unravel_index(np.argmin(df.values), df.shape)
```

This is much faster than `df.stack().idxmin()`.

It gives you a tuple such as `(2, 1)` in your example.  Pass that to df.iloc[] to get the value.

Comment: It works but it is not giving row and column names in output. Also will it work if there are some np.nan values in df?

Comment: @rnso: if you want to ignore NANs, simply use `nanargmin` instead of `argmin`.  If you want the row and column names, you can use `df.columns[x]` and `df.index[y]` or `df.iloc[[x], [y]]` as in jezrael's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or `min`+`min`+`dropna`+`T`+`dropna`+`T`:

```
>>> df[df==df.min(axis=1).min()].dropna(how='all').T.dropna().T
     C2
R3  0.0
>>>
```