# Find min value and index of the value in a matrix column after column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem, which seems to be easy but it is causing me a lot of headache.
The problem is that I'm programming in python (I'm relative new to it) and I'm looking for an aquivalent of the function `max (min)` of a matrix in matlab but using `numpy`.

What I want to do is to get the minimum value and its index in a matrix

Just to keep it as easiest as possible with an example, let's say this is the matrix:

```
arr2D = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 34],
                  [14, 15, 16, 3],
                  [17, 15, 11, 1],
                  [7,   5, 11, 4],
                  [1,  12,  4, 4],
                  [12, 14, 15,-3]])
```

in matlab I would do:

```
[local_max, index] = min(arr2D)
```

and I would get the min value and its index for every column in the matrix.

Trying to repeat the same in python (after looking [here](https://thispointer.com/numpy-amin-find-minimum-value-in-numpy-array-and-its-index/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230067/numpy-minimum-in-row-column-format/3230123)) with the following code:

```
print(np.where(arr2D == np.amin(arr2D, axis = 0)))   # axis 0 is for columns
```

I get the following output:

```
(array([3, 4, 4, 5]), array([1, 0, 2, 3]))
```

which is not really what I want to get!

The expected output should be:

```
[1, 4]   # Meaning the minimum value is 1 and it is in row 4 for the first column
[5, 3]   # Meaning the minimum value is 5 and it is in row 3 for the second column
[4, 4]   # Meaning the minimum value is 4 and it is in row 4 for the third column
[-3, 5]  # Meaning the minimum value is -3 and it is in row 5 for the last column
```

I cannot use the output I get by:

```
print(np.where(arr2D == np.amin(arr2D, axis = 0)))
```

Or I don't understand the output or that's not the right way to get the aquivalent function `max (min)` of matlab.

Could you help me?

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to say that the matrix is float and not integer. I used integer just for the example

Comment: Shouldn't the 1st col min be `1` and 4th be `-3`?

Comment: You are right! I corrected it... thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.amin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) or [`np.min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) returns the min values along an axis

```
np.amin(arr2D, axis=0)
```

Out:

```
array([ 1,  5,  4, -3])
```

[`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) returns the indices

```
np.argmin(arr2D, axis=0)
```

Out:

```
array([4, 3, 4, 5])
```

To get the desired output you can use [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and transpose the array

```
np.vstack([np.amin(arr2D, axis=0), np.argmin(arr2D, axis=0)]).T
```

Out:

```
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 5,  3],
       [ 4,  4],
       [-3,  5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code (you can simply make a function out of it):

```
import numpy as np

arr2D = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 34],
            [14, 15, 16, 3],
            [17, 15, 11, 1],
            [7,   5, 11, 4],
            [1,  12,  4, 4],
            [12, 14, 15,-3]])

flat = arr2D.flatten()
arrayIndex = flat.tolist().index(min(flat))

// results
rowIndex = int(minIndex/arr2D.shape[0])
columnIndex = minIndex % arr2D.shape[1]
```

Comment: Thank a lot! I find the way with 'flatten()' not very intuitive but it seem to work